# Identity auto increment not applied on column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

After the DB Migration when the tables were created in the Database, the Identity Auto-increment was not applied to the 'Id' Column whereas the Primary Key constraint was applied to it.
    Following is the Model class code.

```
public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string domainName { get; set; }
    public string articleID { get; set; }
    public string tld { get; set; }
    public string customerID { get; set; }
    public string customerName { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string nextBillDate { get; set; }

}
```

And following are the columns from the Table that was generated.

[image]

Can someone please help me with how to cleanly apply auto increment in 'Id' Column. I want it to have both the Primary key and the auto increment.

**Edit:**
*I changed the type of Id to int but still the **auto-increment is not applied to it**.Here's a screenshot.*

[image]

Comment: you have a string property as you Unique Columns. It can't be Auto Incremental. Make it an Integer.
`public string Id { get; set; }`

Comment: @MudassarSaleem Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's type [should be `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx) to make it Identity:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: How can I be so dumb!! Thank you!

Comment: the column did get change to int upon update but still the auto-increment is not applied to it.

Comment: Id should be integer in almost every case. ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @VibheshKaul You should do your migration after changes again so that the id changes to int in your DB also.

Comment: @VibheshKaul, if you do not care about data, delete your database and run migration again. Sometimes database is confused when you change the type of some attribute.

Comment: I did that, it still is not having identity applied to it.

Comment: @VibheshKaul Have you tried to input some data to see it applied?

Comment: Please check screenshot int the edit I made to this question.

Comment: @VibheshKaul Have you tried to delete the DB and apply the migration again?

Comment: Yes, it worked after I deleted and re created the database.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after you change your Id from `string` to `int` and the problem still occurs, I recommend that you should delete your database(if you don't care about data) and delete your Migration file from Visual Studio as well. It is important for you to delete your migration file from program because sometimes it doesn't recognized all changes. 
Or, you can add this line of code by hand in your migration file(maybe not recommended, but if nothing helps, this will help):

```
identity: true
```

So, it should look something like this:

```
CreateTable("dbo.Table",
            c => new
            {
                Id= c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                ...
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything like this,

```
private int _id = -1; 
public int Id {get => _name; set => _name = value};
```

Just remove it and try this,

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This solved my problem